# Timezone offset format

Tags: jsonschema

I'm using [an implementation](https://github.com/swaggest/php-json-schema) of json-schema. In the implementation package,  date-time format which API is sending (`2019-08-26T12:32:42.503+0000`) is considered as `Invalid date-time format`. However, it is accepting `2019-08-26T12:32:42.503+00:00`. Is implementation wrong or API? How can avoid this mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema uses [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5) to define [date-time](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3.1) format, `2019-08-26T12:32:42.503+0000` is not a valid RFC3339 representation so it does not qualify to pass JSON Schema validation as `date-time`.

Validation example with `ajv`: https://runkit.com/embed/9w3x5nrxnk1e